# RVM installation error linux ubuntu 16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I am beginning out the with web development. I was trying to install RVM by following the steps given in http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux

But when I try installing the RVM ([step 3.1](http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/linux#step3-1)) via the terminal I get the error:

[image]

Comment: Did you run `gpg2 --keyserver ...` like it suggested?

Comment: Inlined the image so the error is actually visible

Comment: yes, I did as it suggested @Brian

Answer (score 1):

RVM is trying to check the authenticity of the file you have downloaded using the version of GPG you have installed, but it appears that your GPG trust database is inaccessible (or may not exist) per the error "can't open /home/sumitsh/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg :Permission denied".

You can reset the permissions to the trust database as follows:

```
chmod 0700 /home/sumitsh/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg
```

Then re-run the command.

Comment: I get an error  `chmod: changing permissions of '/home/sumitsh/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg': Operation not permitted` after using the 'chmod 0700 /home/sumitsh/ .gnupg/trustdb.gpg '